# Cypress - Assign, modify and Accessing variables over function. Variables reset to original value

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress, gui-testing

In the below piece of code, variables a and b are reset to original values rather than values assigned in between.

```
let a = 'abc';
let z = 'def';
cy.wrap($node).find(#someElementA).invoke('text').then((one) => {
    a = one;
    cy.log('A->', a);
})
cy.wrap($node).find(#someElementB).invoke('text').then((two) => {
    z = two;
    cy.log('Z->' + z);
})
cy.log('Outer->'+ A +  Z);
```

The Logs are as below

```
Actual Result-

A-> One
Z-> Two
Outer-> abc def



Expected Result-

A-> One
Z-> Two
Outer-> One Two
```

How do I ensure I get updated value and I would need both values together for my rest of the purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `cy.then()` wrapper before using the values, that will ensure the commands have had time to execute

```js
let a = 'abc';
let z = 'def';
cy.wrap($node).find(#someElementA).invoke('text').then((one) => {
    a = one;
    cy.log('A->', a);
})
cy.wrap($node).find(#someElementB).invoke('text').then((two) => {
    z = two;
    cy.log('Z->' + z);
})

cy.then(() => {
  cy.log('Outer->'+ A +  Z)  // values are not changed until above code finishes
})
```